# Stop if statement when condition is met

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm displaying the ***first*** value that is `>= 5` out of an array of random numbers spanning 0-10. I'm currently using `event.stopPropagation();` to end the function so the `span` isn't replaced by the final `data.val >= 5`. While this works just fine, it's throwing a console error: `Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined`

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Is there a better way to tackle this?

```
function numbers(data) {
  if (data.val >= 5)  {
    $('span').html(data.val);
    event.stopPropagation(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see how you're using this function.

Comment: where do you pass `event` ? it must be like function `numbers(data,event)` or you can directly use `break`

Comment: is our function running inside an event handler? Event is not defined if your function was not called be a triggered event handler.

Comment: If `if` condition returns `false` at `data.val >= 5` why is `event.stopPropagation()` needed ?

Comment: I get that `event.stopPropagation()` is the wrong thing to use here. It is working, but I'm looking for an alternative way that doesn't throw errors.

Comment: @user1661677 Can include full `html` , `js` at Question ? , create stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ to demonstrate ?

Comment: Full HTML and JS is much too long. I just need to stop displaying JSON objects when the `if` condition is met.

Comment: `if` condition should prevent `$('span').html(data.val)` from being called when `data.val >= 5` returns `false` ; `event.stopPropagation()` could be removed ? What is the `event` ?

Comment: yes it could be removed, but `if` statement would continue running after it returns `true`, replacing content in the `span`. I need it to only show the FIRST value `>= 5`

Comment: Why would `if` condition return `true` after `data.val >= 5` ? Does `data.val` value increment from `0` to `10` ?  Try substituting `.append()` for `.html()`